# Which drive should be uses to persist data in azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure

In my azure virtual machine i selected windows server 2008 r2 image from quick created. When I log into the machine, i see there are two drive. On which drive i should ftp my application because I am not sure which drive will persist if machine is moved.

Also how much data i can persist on each different type of VM, is there a limit depend on my vm size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Windows Azure Virtual Machine for Windows you can find drive C and D.

Drive C is the boot OS disk and the size is actually the size of your VHD you have either uploaded or configured from the Gallery. This disk is the persisted disk so anything you will store on drive C will be persisted.  In the preview the Windows Server R2 VHD from Gallery id default 30 GB in size that's why you may see 30 GB size in drive C: however you can create upto 128 GB VHD and deploy by your own with medium and above Virtual Machine instance.

The storage space on drive D: is the temporary storage as indicated in the above table, where a Medium is expected to be 100 GB. This space is NOT peristed in Windows Azure storage and will be destroyed if the Virtual Machine needs to be migrated due to bad hardware.

About your question on how much data can be persisted on Windows Azure Virtual machine, the data size which can persist on Windows Azure Virtual Machine is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156003.aspx).

1. Extra Small -  20 GB
2. Small       -  20 GB
3. Medium      - 100 GB
4. Large       - 200 GB
5. Extra Large - 400 GB

Comment: I am not completely understand. You wrote than drive D: is temporary, but later you telling than size of data can be persisted on VM depends on VM size... If I deploy my application to VM, should I use drive C: or drive D: ? What is the purpose of drive D: if it's temporal?

Comment: @AlexShapovalov - D: will persist across reboots, but if the virtual machine is migrated to other hardware, eg during Microsoft Azure patching, or bad hardware, etc., you will lose the D:.  So it persists across reboots but not across migrations.

Comment: I think on Linux the permanent drive is `/dev/sda1` and the temporary drive is `/dev/sdb1`. Would be great to add to your answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Each Azure virtual machine has, by default, two drives. The default c: drive is a vhd in blob storage connaected as storage to your virtual machine and is the persistant drive. See the technical diagram and description of creating virtual machines here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/other-resources/command-line-tools/

Any drives you connect to the virtual machine will be, ultimately, vhd's in blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the limit does depend on your VM size.

Each data disk that you attach to an Azure Virtual Machine has a maximum capacity of 1 TB (current max size for a page blob which backs this data disk). So with an extra large VM you can have 16 TB of persistant geo-replicated storage (if you enable this in your storage account).

VM Size     Data Disk Limit

Extra Small 1

Small       2

Medium      4

Large       8

Extra Large 16

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/