# Windows Azure D drive shows empty

Tags: azure-storage, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a virtual machine of Windows Azure. I have two drive i.e. **C drive and D drive**. I go to property of **D drive**. It shows 4 gb used space but when I go to **D drive** it shows empty. There is no any files, data. I have also setup Sql Server 2012 on **D drive**.

How can I recover my data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a VM in azure, by default you will see two drives in windows explorer: C & D. By default the D: drive will be named "Temporary Storage (D:)". This isn't a very clear warning, and I'm sorry to say you have lost whatever data you had stored there. The D: drive that is created by default in an Azure VM should be considered volatile storage, as its contents are not persisted in Azure Storage like the C: drive is. In other words only store things on D: temporarily as they can be deleted at any time.

Also, see [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983750/which-drive-should-be-uses-to-persist-data-in-azure-virtual-machine).